# Switch From Default Cursor To Wait Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to have the cursor change from default to wait cursor when user hit submit. I tried this but it doesn't work. I am copying files from, To, so until the progress is done the cursor must be wait cursor. thanks

```
     // Starts the process of copying in background worker

     backgroundCopy.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
     this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

     private void backgroundCopy_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {

                //Enable Submit Button
                Submit.Enabled = true;

                // Set Progress Bar to Green
                progressBar1.SetState(1);

                this.lblInfo.Text = "Copy Completed!";

                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
```

Comment: Set the form's UseWaitCursor property instead.  So it doesn't matter that the mouse hovers a child control, like a button.

Comment: I only want it to switch when submit is clicked and stays like that until process is finished

Comment: Sure, that is obvious.  Replace the this.Cursor assignments.

Comment: @HansPassant may i have more details.

Answer (score 0):

As @[HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) says, you just need to replace the [Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursors?view=netframework-4.8) assignments in order to set [which cursor you want to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursors.waitcursor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Cursors_WaitCursor).

Something like this would fit

```
private void backgroundCopy_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        //DO WORK
        // Set Progress Bar to Green
        progressBar1.SetState(1);
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "stil doesn't work"? It's not applying the cursor? Bear in mind that if you're using a `BackgroundWorker` , as your example code shown, you're at the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, not `ProgressChanged`

Comment: backgroundCopy_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                //Enable Submit Button
                Submit.Enabled = true;
                Clear.Enabled = true;
                // Set Progress Bar to Green
                progressBar1.SetState(1);
                this.lblInfo.Text = "Copy Completed!";
                
            }
            finally
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            }

Comment: i also tried:  private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor; //other code}all other code works but the wait cursor.